# LINQ with JOIN Operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by, sql-to-linq-conversion

i would like to have a  LINQ statementlike this

in Simple words
i have two tables A and B. A contains fields id,name,amt1,userid. Table B contains id,userid,amt2.  I wanted the details of table A in which A.userid=B.userid but B.id!=A.id

Can any one helpmeout. Am a beginner in LINQ
Thanks in advance

Comment: Rephrase your answer's title avoiding tags and common phrases

Comment: You have **duplicates**, is this what you want to say?

Comment: What is the purpose of "act.id != sav.accountid". Explain in your words how the data looks and the business logic

Comment: Presumably the records are repeating because a join over `userid` creates a m:n relationship over those two tables

Comment: I have edited the question .Please have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Yes am using Entity Framework and thus LINQ to Entities

Comment: name your post properly anyway, please!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
TableA.Join(TableB, a => a.userid, b => b.userid, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
      .Where(j => j.A.id != j.B.id)
      .Select(j => j.A)
```

Human SQL would be:

```
select a.* 
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.userid = b.userid 
where a.id != b.id;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493861/sql-to-linq-conversion-with-not-in   please refer the link for related answers.