# SQL to LINQ conversion with NOT IN

Tags: c#, sql-to-linq-conversion

please form a LINQ query for the mysql query

```
select a.name ,a.amount 
from acount as a 
where a.acountid NOT IN (select c.id from saving as c where c.userid="x") 
and a.userid="x";
X=1;
```

Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: do you need a linq expression for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have not tested at all but something in these lines should work...

```
var query =    
    from a in db.Account
    where !(from s in db.Savings 
            where s.UserId == "x"
            select s.id)    
           .Contains(a.AccountId)    
    && a.UserId == "x"
    select new { a.Name, a.Amount };
```